# Async/Await and Cross Thread Exceptions

Tags: .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, asynchronous, async-await

I have a dialog form with a TextBox that fires a TextChanged event. When the length of the text entered is greater than 1 it makes a request to a web service to get matching data. The web service is using a TaskCompletionSource.

When no web service call is required I can see that the TextChanged method is called on the same thread as the method which opened the dialog. Similarly if I get the results using the TaskCompletionSource  .Result on my web service call, again the same thread is used.

However, if I change the TextChanged method to be 'async' and use 'await' with the web service call, I suddenly see the TextChanged method moved to a different thread (using Visual Studio Parallel Stacks viewer) and my call to update a control in the dialog fails with a cross-thread exception.

I am not using any Task.Run in the method chain. I do not understand why a new thread is started resulting in a need to use Invoke on my dialog controls. Can anyone shed any light on why this is happening and if there is a fix.

Answer (score 0):

After much debugging I discovered that the method which created the dialog box was calling an async method on the dialog box and used ConfigureAwait(false). This caused a new thread to be created. I also got a new thread if I added a ConfigureAwait(false) to the web service call within the textchanged event.

Thus I guess I need to be careful where ConfigureAwait(false) gets used. Any hints or tips on this welcome.

Comment: Use ConfigureAwait(false) always unless you're in a UI environment and you're using `async void`s

Comment: Literally, use `ConfigureAwait(false)` if you don't care about the thread where the code *within the same `async` method* will continue executing after `await`. E.g., if you don't need to access the UI after `await`, it's safe to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Note, it's the synchronization context that gets captured and restored by `await`. E.g., a console application doesn't have s. context, so `ConfigureAwait` would not do anything for a console app.

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, you should consider using [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/data/gg577609.aspx).

I have a few articles on the [Nokia Developer Wiki](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/) on the subject:

1. [Observable vs. Task](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Observable_vs._Task)
2. [Exposing the Geolocator as a Reactive Service](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Exposing_the_Geolocator_as_a_Reactive_Service)

I don't have an example with a TextBox but I'm sure you'll easily find one as it's the canonical sample. With throttling and all.

There's also a StackOverflow tag for it: [system.reactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system.reactive)